# How to add delay in xv6?

Tags: c, time, xv6

Problem:
I need to reboot xv6 after a particular amount of time.
However, delay() and sleep() do not work. How can I add delay of specific time in sysproc.c

Comment: What have you tried? Where's the [mcve] of your attempt? And please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: just of curiosity, do you take the MIT course to build the system ?  Where did you find the resources to work on xv6 ?  On which hardware are you running it ?

Comment: I am nott aking any course, its a university work. 
I'm using xv6 on qemu on ubuntu in vmware. The task was to implement a system call in xv6 that will reboot the system after some specific amount of time-lets say 10s- .
I have implemented the call and it reboots. But I have no idea how to add delay.